# MySQL multiple results with find in set of values

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, find-in-set

I need to get multiple rows with articles where the article IDs are in the list below. (in the string list)

```
SELECT id, title FROM articles WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, "1,2,3,4,5,9,25");
```

How to do that correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id, title 
FROM articles 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, '1,2,3,4,5,9,25') <> 0
```